# Create and save a thumbnail from an image which is loaded from a file

Tags: c#, .net, vba

How can I create and save a thumbnail from an image which is loaded from a file in VBA?

1. Load image into memory based on string which defines path to file
2. Make thumbnail of that image
3. Save that image to folder as jpg

I know how to write this in C#. I tried to make an external exe file for this purpose but somehow it does not work when I try to run it via VBA Shell however it works if I pass an argument to it normally via Windows Explorer.

This is full C# code of ThumbMaker:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            string inputPath = args[0];
            string outputPath = args[1];
            try
            {
                Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@inputPath);
                b.GetThumbnailImage(160, 160, null, IntPtr.Zero).Save(outputPath);
                Console.WriteLine(inputPath);
                Console.WriteLine(outputPath);
                Console.WriteLine(b.Height);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong, probably input file could not be converted to bitmap");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You must run this program with 2 parameters");
            Console.WriteLine("1. is inputPath , 2. is outputPath");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically what I needed to translate to VBA:

```
Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@inputPath);
b.GetThumbnailImage(160, 160, null, IntPtr.Zero).Save(outputPath);
```

This VBA attempt is not working:

```
Private Sub UploadButton_Click()

    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument1 As String
    Dim strArgument2 As String

    strProgramName = Initialization.ImagesPath & "ThumbnailMaker.exe"
    strArgument1 = PathTextBox.Text
    'strArgument2 = ImageID & "_img" & ImageNumber & ".jpg"
    strArgument2 = "newIMG.jpg"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument1 & """ """ & strArgument2 & """", 1) 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

well assuming that you are trying to create the thumbnail using an external program, i would just go for this:

```
Process.Start("C:/Path/ThumbnailMaker.exe", "Your Arguments for the external 
Program here i.e. the filepath: Initialization.ImagesPath")
```

then if you can specify the output name of the file with your 3rd party program, you can as well just use this argument and then grab the file since you already got the name. Otherwise, if this Program uses randomizes output filenames for any reason, work with a systemfilewatch and get your filename.

Comment: VBA doesn't have `Process.Start()`. It uses a function called [**`Shell()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437.aspx).

Comment: my bad, i must have been confused with the tags, they got edited, was vb.net first